# Python email.mime sometimes sends body text as attachments

Tags: python, email, mime-types, mime

I am working with the python email.mime library to generate emails for monitoring system status across a number of locations.  I attach data to the body of the email as described in examples and documentation and often I get the email just as expected: lines of text with the data I need (within the body of the email).

In some cases, however, I get the text within an attachment.  Here's what I see when I diff two of the emails in raw format:

```
---===============1782456183745610843756==
-Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"; name="ATT00001"
+--===============4561084375674561084375==
+Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
-Content-Description: ATT00001
-Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ATT00001"
```

The way I want the email sent is as text within the body. Some locations always attach it as an untyped text file, while others always append it to the body of the email.

I am looking for differences in how the emails are generated, but it is literally the same code generating both, so it must be some site-specific parameter.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

It has to do with how Microsoft servers interpret the components of the email.  I would build the emails in pieces: first the main part was constructed, and then additional metadata was computed and attached via msg.attach.  This data was supposed to be handled as part of the body of the email (and it is when it is sent through some email servers).  However, when the email is routed through MS Exchange servers, it takes the additional parts of the email and treats them as attachments.

I was able to piece it together and found evidence for it here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/mailflow/message-body-shown-as-attachment

https://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187